# "successful" MySQL dump with no result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a weird problem trying to upload a heavy MySQL dump file into a database.
The PuTTY command I'm using is the following:

```
homedirectory/userfolder/    mysql -u username –-password=password database_name < file.sql
```

The procedure runs as it would normally do (I've done this many times already) but when I look for the table that was supposed to be created in 'database_name' I dont see it!

Maybe it is because the file is too big? (4,5GB).

The command used to obtain the dump file was:

```
mysqldump --user=user --password=password --no-create-db 
-h localhost --single-transaction --lock-tables=false 
--skip-tz-utc database_name table_name > file.sql
```

After getting the .sql file, from the same location I ran the command and it seems to work for a few moments, dont get any error messages or any of the like.
After it finishes "loading" I check my database but the table is not there.

Not sure what else to specify, this is a simple procedure I do regularly and I have never had any complications, or at least never without at least an error message.

Comment: It's really hard to answer your question when it's that vague.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's because I thought if the error is the size then the only info required was that, I will specify it better.

Comment: This question would probably be better answered on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

I recently tried creating sql dump using these commands :

```
backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

restore:# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

Please refer to this link for more information you may need:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Ekta, I am already using these same commnds although the problem I think rests in the size of the file I am trying to upload, which is of 4.5GB, but thank you for your comment!